# How can I type bopomofo on Windows without converting to hanzi?

Tags: zhuyin-fuhao, input-methods

I've just finished my two months travelling in China and have arrived to spend one month in Taiwan.

I now want to learn as much as I can about how Mandarin Chinese is used here.

One thing different in Taiwan is that people type using Zhuyin Fuhao a.k.a. bopomofo. So I want to learn both bopomofo and how to type it.

A website I'm using to learn bopomofo via flashcards requires me to type in bopomofo to test myself. There are a good few IMEs in Windows 7 for traditional Chinese and I've fiddled with a couple of them but have not found out how to enter "raw" bopomofo without the IME converting to characters.

### To illustrate:

To enter a character such as `馬` you would type `ㄇㄚˇ`

But in certain situations you don't want `ㄇㄚˇ` to be converted to `馬`, you just want it to stay as `ㄇㄚˇ`.

How can this be done? (The website is memrise.com but please don't just suggest some other site or app to help me learn, because I'm curious to figure out how to enter bopomofo anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the default installed Chinese language pack (Chinese Traditional Taiwan Microsoft BoPoMo)
2. When typing, try using the space bar, this works for characters that don't represent anything by themselves (ㄅㄆㄇㄈㄉㄊㄋㄌ etc...). This won't work for characters that are associated with words (ㄚ=阿, ㄞ=哀, ㄛ=喔)
3. For ㄅㄆㄇ that are associated with words, you will have to scroll down and pick what you want. A little more of a hassle, but still works.
4. Tones can be used by themselves. just insert them and press space bar (ˊ ˇ ˋ ˙) But I will warn you beforehand, they are written in superscript and hard to read.

Answer (score 4):

Use your own IME:

1) [image]

2) Make sure that your IME is:

[image]

3) Choose "Phoetic" and directly input what you want.

Comment: Yes this is IME I installed when I got to Taiwan. But it seems I didn't explain well enough that my problem is how to type bopomofo and get it to stay as bopomofo and NOT converted. Installing it is the easy part!

Comment: I'm really sorry for my inability to explain this in a way you can understand. I *can* type `ㄇㄚˇ` but it always gets converted to `馬`, even when I want it to stay as `ㄇㄚˇ`.

Comment: There is of course one huge disadvantage with downloading and installing this IME for a Chinese learner. The installer is only in Chinese and has many options and popup windows which a learner has no hope of coping with unless a Chinese friend is there to guide them through. This is one advantage the IMEs that come with a computer or OS have - they do not assume that only fluent native speakers will have occasion to use them and have options, menus, popups, settings, help, etc in English or the language of the OS.

Comment: Well……Sorry but you can just use IME，I've upgrated the answer;)

Comment: I did have the MS simplified IME installed but when I installed the Sogou IME it seems to have taken the place of the MS one instead of just adding itself to the end of the list `\-:`

Comment: But it does seem that I can now type `ㄇㄚ` - so in the end we have a good answer - thank you!

Comment: Don't mention it.

Comment: Point #1 is now broken and just says "enter image description here"

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy to me, are you using MS IME?

follow the tutorial in this page
http://goo.gl/PAAj2

when you reach the "Add Input Language" part, select "Chinese(Traditional) - Phonetic", then save setting, then switch your IME to "Chinese(Traditional) - Phonetic", press any bopomofo characters you want, then press space bar, the characters you want should appear(sometimes you have to select them from a list).

Comment: Well I want to use MS IME to type in Pinyin and have another keyboard/IME to type in Bopomofo. I don't think it's possible to install two instances of the same MS IME, one with each setting. I didn't foresee this though when I posted the question. This is also the case with CA55CE37's solution which I didn't realize immediately.

Comment: I can have multiple input methods, and each has a different keyboard layout(I've just tried), don't know where your problem is. When you say Pinyin, did you mean the input method used in mainland china? If so, you should be able to have Pinyin and "Chinese(Traditional) - Phonetic" coexist and each has a different setting.

Comment: Yes I can have two *different* IMEs installed but I can't have two copies of the *same* IME with different settings installed. As I already use the **MS IME** for typing Pinyin for Simplified Chinese I can't also use the **MS IME** for typing bopomofo for Traditional Chinese. But the answers so far tell me how to change the MS IME settings, thus leaving it no longer able to type pinyin for simplified Chinese.

Comment: I can have the Chinese Traditional Phonetic, but that leads to my original problem in my question, that the bopomofo is always converted to hanzi, and sometimes I don't want it converted.

Comment: Just trying to help, when you say MS IME did you mean the language bar? while IME refers to input methods?(I am not a native speaker) If so, your MS IME should be able to install different input methods. Press "EN" button on the language bar to change your location then cycle through each input methods by pressing ctrl+shift. There are many input methods for chinese, the input method for doing Pinyin and the input method for doing bopomofo is different. It is strange for you to say that you want to do both(Pinyin and bopomofo)in one input method.

Comment: I apologize for the language barrier. The "language bar" is the place that shows which of your installed keyboard layouts and IMEs is the active one. I currently have several keyboard layouts for other languages plus two IMEs for Chinese installed. I have one Pinyin IME and one bopomofo IME. I do *not* want to do both Pinyin and bopomofo in one single IME. The Pinyin IME is working fine for simplified input. The bopomofo works fine for traditional input. What I am missing is being able to input bopomofo without it being converted to traditional, while keeping my pinyin IME intact.

Comment: That's probably because you are using "New" phonetic(新注音), install "Chinese(Traditional) - Phonetic" to your language bar, and switch to it and use it then you should be find.

Comment: I am using **a)** "Chinese (Simplified, PRC)" : "Chinese (Simplified) - Microsoft Pinyin New Experience Input Style" and **b)** "Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan)" : "Chinese Traditional New Phonetic". I can change these to any IMEs that have English user interfaces if necessary.

Comment: I don't know whether there is a English interface or not, because i don't have a english OS to see. Apparently you are using new phonetic, you will have to change it to "old" phonetic, which is "Chinese(Traditional) - Phonetic". If there is no English interface to it, then you have to get used to it. Because nowadays every Traditional Chinese input method work like new phonetic, they pick characters for you when you type bopomofo in, there is no input method specifically for input bopomofo only.

Comment: I've now installed "Chinese (Traditional) - Phonetic". It does have an English user interface. As I've said, all the ones that come with Windows do, but ones that must be downloaded from Chinese or Taiwanese websites often don't. I'm just testing it now to see if it will work with memrise.com ...

Comment: So, have you succeed?

Comment: So far I'm so bad at it that I can't really say (-: But I have installed both the old and new MS Zhuyin IMEs. The newer one is better for everything except typing raw bopomofo. The older one *seems* better at entering raw bopomofo but I'm not sure yet.

Comment: You will probably need something like below:
http://goo.gl/ulTwgB
http://goo.gl/uniFpD
These thing are called "中文鍵盤貼紙" in Chinese.
It will allow you to put bopomofos on your keyboard.

Comment: Thanks user3226059. I've learned to touch type a few languages / scripts (badly) by remembering the keyboard layouts, so I'm used to making do without the symbols on the physical keys.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Rime](http://rimeime.googlecode.com) and Chuimfuhau schema from [the Rime-aca project](https://code.google.com/p/rime-aca/).

Next, type bopomofo in pinyin. Enjoy the ease.